# youtube_dl.utils.SameFileError | python, youtube_dl

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-dl, yt

I am new to `youtube_dl` and I want to download a youtube playlist in mp3 and after researching a lot, I was able to code this:

```py
import youtube_dl
from time import sleep
# the playlist url
yt_url = input('Enter playlist URL: ')

print('Fetching playlist...')
# Gets the playlist and stores the video info in a list
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})
with ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(yt_url, download=False)
    if 'entries' in result:
        video = result['entries']
        
        playlist = []
        for i, item in enumerate(video):
            video = result['entries'][i]
            playlist.append(video)

# Looping the list to download all the videos one by
# one, named as 1.mp3, 2.mp3, 3.mp3 and so on
a = 0
for video in playlist:
    a = a + 1
    ydl_opts = {'outtmpl': f'{a}.mp3'}
    print(f"\nDownloading {video['title']} (https://youtube.com/watch?v={video['id']}) as {a}.mp3...")
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={video['id']}")
    sleep(0.5)
    print('Done.')
print('\n\nTask Finished.')
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Downloading otherside (https://youtube.com/watch?v=kK81m-A3qpU) as 1.mp3...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/! workspace/goffy/files/bots/music/a/download.py", line 27, in <module>
    ydl.download(f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={video['id']}")
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2063, in download
    raise SameFileError(outtmpl)
youtube_dl.utils.SameFileError: 1.mp3
```

I don't even have any file named `1.mp3`, I only have a file named `download.py` which contains that code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting the download URL in a list because that's what the `download` function expects:

```py
        ydl.download([f"https://youtube.com/watch?v={video['id']}"])
```

Then [this check](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/b797c1cc750b1f617678281731303611e21c70d0/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L2056-L2063) that raises the `SameFileError` exception should pass because `len(url_list)` will be 1.

At the moment `len(url_list)` is the number of characters in the URL because it's not wrapped in a `list`.

Comment: hey! thank you so much. your answer helped. but it downloads as a .webm (`[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "1.mp3.webm"`) and also sometimes as .mkv (`WARNING: Requested formats are incompatible for merge and will be merged into mkv.`, `[ffmpeg] Merging formats into "2.mp3.mkv"`), i want them to only be in .mp3 format and not .webm or .mkv. Also they are very large in size, `39.10MiB`, `37.56MiB`. Well i don't really care about the size as much but could you please tell me how i can download them as a mp3 or convert them to a mp3?

Comment: There's an example in the [docs](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl) on how to convert a video to mp3. Could you please mark this answer as correct if it fixed your `SameFileError` and create a new question for questions that aren't related to the file error?

Comment: thanks for your help 